# Spring cloud gateway with Kubernetes for incoming traffic limiting

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-gateway

I have spring boot service which is running on distributed VMs, but I want to move that service to Kubernetes. Previously we had spring cloud gateway configured for request limiter across those 4 VMs, but now with Kubernetes, my application will be auto-scalable.

In that case, how can I limit the requests given that, Kubernetes could increase or decrease the pods based on traffic? How can I maintain the state of the incoming traffic but still keep my service stateless?

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, you can do rate limiting by fronting your application with a proxy. (nginx, haproxy, etc). More specifically you can use a [Kubernetes Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). More specifically you can use the [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and the can use something like [limit rate](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#limit-rate) in the ConfigMap or [rate limiting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rate-limiting) through annotations in the ingress.

Comment: Thank you for response, I am trying Ingress now as of now. I will keep this thread updated how that turns out.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [istio service mesh's rate limiting feature](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/) which has the following concepts for rate limiting traffic in k8s:

- QuotaSpec
- QuotaSpecBinding
- quota instance
- [memquota adapter](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/adapters/memquota/)
- [quota rule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/quota/)

Comment: Thanks Vikram, I am more inclined towards Ingress. But I will keep this thread updated on my progress.